# How to pass props in child component in react native with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a parent component:

```
const [OTPNotify, setOTPNotify] = useState("flex");

const closeOTPNotify = () => {
  setOTPNotify("none");
}

<OTPRibbonComponent onCancel={closeOTPNotify} display={OTPNotify}/>
```

My Child Component:

```
export interface OTPNotifyComponentProps {
    onCancel?: any;
    display?: string,
}
const OTPRibbonComponent = (props: OTPNotifyComponentProps) => {
    const {onCancel} = props;
    const display = props.display;
    return (
        <>
            <LinearGradient style={[styles.linearGradient, {display: display}]}>
                <Text>
                    Please Complete OTP Process
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={onCancel}>
                    <Icon name={'close-box-outline'} size={22} color={Colors.textDark} style={styles.iconStyle}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </LinearGradient>
      </>
    )
}
```

I want my child component to change its display from `flex`
to `none`, when I click on the `Icon`.

But I am getting error at `{display: display}`

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: LinearGradientProps | Readonly<LinearGradientProps>): LinearGradient', gave the following error.
    Type '{ display: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle> | RecursiveArray<ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle>> | readonly (ViewStyle | ... 1 more ... | RegisteredStyle<...>)[]'.
      Types of property 'display' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"none" | "flex" | undefined'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"none" | "flex" | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: LinearGradientProps, context: any): LinearGradient', gave the following error.
    Type '{ display: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle> | RecursiveArray<ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle>> | readonly (ViewStyle | ... 1 more ... | RegisteredStyle<...>)[]'.
      Types of property 'display' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"none" | "flex" | undefined'.ts(2769)
const display: string | undefined
  Types of property 'display' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"none" | "flex" | undefined'.
```

I am very new to using react native using typescript, and I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Only a tip to try, use "display?: any;". This is a type error. the string is much generic. I do not know the styles types of React, then I can't help you solve this with a "good" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
export interface OTPNotifyComponentProps {
    onCancel?: any;
    display?: 'none' | 'flex',
}
```